# Adicionar linha da tabela B à tabela A com base nas condições

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho duas tabelas de dados, sendo elas:
tabela A  e tabela B. 
Eu quero juntar as linhas da tabela B com A nas seguintes condições:

Se uma linha ocorrer em B e não em A, adicione-a a A.
Se uma linha ocorrer mais em B do que ocorre em A, adicione-a a A até que ela ocorra com tanta frequência em A quanto em B.
Se eu tiver as duas tabelas a seguir:

`TabelaA  TabelaB
 2 4 1 3  2 2 2 1
 2 2 2 1  2 4 1 3
 4 5 2 4  2 4 1 3
 1 4 2 5  2 4 1 3
 2 4 1 3  5 3 2 3`

Eu quero ter a seguinte tabela:

`Tabela A + B
  2 2 2 1
  2 4 1 3
  2 4 1 3
  2 4 1 3
  4 5 2 4
  1 4 2 5
  5 3 2 3`

É possível conseguir isso com uma consulta sql?

Comment: Cada um dos elementos das tabelas está num coluna diferente? Por exemplo, a 1ª linha da tabela `A`, "2 4 1 3", são 4 colunas diferentes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Se uma linha ocorrer em B e não em A, adicione-a a A.*

Você resolve isto com teoria dos conjuntos. Basta fazer

```
A U (B - A)
```

que é implementado em SQL por

```
-- código #1
SELECT distinct A1, A2, A3, A4 from B
minus 
SELECT distinct B1, B2, B3, B4 from A;
```

O código acima lista a primeira parte do que deve ser acrescentado em A.
Dependendo do gerenciador de banco de dados não é necessário utilizar a cláusula DISTINCT.